# Remove all texts until certain string in multiple text files using python

Tags: nlp, text-files, text-manipulation

I have 14680 text files and after certain String I want to delete all the lines in each text files, how to accomplish this using python

Thanks and Regards

Comment: You read in each file line by line, and once the String matches your input, you stop and save what you have read in so far.

Comment: I am new to python so it would be help full if I have the code or basic syntax